# CSS transition aborted by end of function

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, css-transitions

I am trying to make a carousel (I know there already are a lot like bootstrap's but I think it is a good learning exercise) so I've made a trick to add a fade transition. I set the element to be display as active with `opacity : 0;` and set it to 1. I made a transition: `opacity 1s;` on the active element so I hoped it would fade in in front of the previous element.
That's exactly what happens when I debug the code (Chrome debugger) but in real speed there is no transition... I'm pretty sure it's because the function ends before the end of the transition but I didn't expect it to happen...
Here is the js function I use:

```
next.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var nbItems = itemsCollection.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < nbItems; i++) {
    var j = (i+1)%nbItems;
    var itemAttributes = itemsCollection[i].className.split(" ");
    if(itemAttributes.indexOf("active") > -1){
      itemsCollection[j].style.opacity = "0";
      itemsCollection[i].className = "item transition";
      itemsCollection[j].className = "item active";
      itemsCollection[j].style.opacity = "1";
      itemsCollection[i].className = "item";
      document.querySelector(".carousel .indicator.target-" + i).className = "indicator target-" + i;
      document.querySelector(".carousel .indicator.target-" + j).className = "indicator target-" + j + " active";
      break;
    }
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot: .item, .item.transition and .item.active are used to define different z-indexes

Comment: Click the edit link below the question to add things you forgot.